# Migrate orders, products, categories, customers from Magento 1.5 to Magento 2.0

Tags: php, magento, migration

I have Magento store with old version 1.5.0.1.

I want to migrate data from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

It has 5000 products, 1000 orders, 4000 customers. Now I am going to create my website with Magento 2.1.7 version. I want to migrate all data like orders, products, categories, customers from Magento old server 1.5 to new server 2.1.7.

Can anyone tell me please what is the best way to migrate data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i hope you will get solution here.... if you dont get solution here, post here once : https://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

For up-gradation you can use https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-pro/ this module.

or export all data in csv format and upload the csv in magento2 according to magento2 or customer password is md5 in magento 1 you need to use the below extension to support md5 password 
https://github.com/sinisa86/Sinwashere_LegacyAuthentication